# Sum function in a sql query

Tags: informix

I have the below query:

```
SELECT 
     cc.chain_desc as chain_desc 
    ,cc.chain_id as chain_id 
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) as TranCount
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
WHERE 
t.loc_country = 'U' 
AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC') 
GROUP BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id 
ORDER BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id
```

The above query when executed, gives me the below result:

[image]

I need a sum of the final column "trancount" which will be 490. I have tried changing the query as below:

```
SELECT 
     cc.chain_desc as chain_desc 
    ,cc.chain_id as chain_id 
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) as TranCount
    ,SUM(distinct t.trans_id)as TransSum
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
WHERE 
t.loc_country = 'U'
AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC')
GROUP BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id 
ORDER BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id
```

But I didnt get the expected result. What is the right way to do a summation of the transcount column?.

Comment: `Group by grouping sets` (SQL Server) or `With Rollup` (mySQL)

Comment: Yeah - which RDBMS?

Comment: Using Informix.

Comment: If you are using Informix why did you tag either mysql OR sql-server???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

== EDITED VERSION ==
Try (in SQL Server):

```
SELECT 
     chain_desc
    ,chain_id
    ,TranCount
    ,SUM(TranCount) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) as TransSum
    (
        SELECT 
             cc.chain_desc as chain_desc 
            ,cc.chain_id as chain_id 
            ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) as TranCount
        FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
        ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
        ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
        ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
        ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
        WHERE 
        t.loc_country = 'U' 
        AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
        AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
        and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
        AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC') 
        GROUP BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id 
    ) as a
    ORDER BY chain_desc, chain_id
```

and remove the `GROUP BY`

Comment: On doing the above, Im getting multiple rows as below:

chain_desc chain_id trancount transum
  66 490
  66 490
  66 490
  66 490
LOVES 2 212 490
LOVES 2 212 490
LOVES 2 212 490
LOVES 2 212 490
LOVES 2 212 490
LOVES 2 212 490

Comment: you could also try to mess around with distinct

Comment: Getting this error when I try the query:


ERROR com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;  near '(PARTITION BY 1) as TransSum

Comment: Ah, you are using MySQL - Sorry, i thought you are using SqlServer (Microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     cc.chain_desc as chain_desc 
    ,cc.chain_id as chain_id 
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) as TranCount
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
WHERE 
t.loc_country = 'U' 
AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC') 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id), ())
ORDER BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id
```

Group by grouping sets allows you to do multiple levels of aggregation those values not aggregated will Reuther NULL

or perhpas you need with rollup if MySQL...

```
SELECT 
     cc.chain_desc as chain_desc 
    ,cc.chain_id as chain_id 
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) as TranCount
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
WHERE 
t.loc_country = 'U' 
AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC') 
GROUP BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id with Rollup 
ORDER BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id
```